# Is it possible to perform one-way OTR MITM?

Tags: cryptography, man-in-the-middle, key-exchange, diffie-hellman, off-the-record

Here's something that is bugging me recently: suppose that me and my friend establish an OTR session and - as a result of that - DH key exchange is performed. My friend verifies my key, but I cannot verify his fingerprint. Despite that, we have a secure channel over which he can send me one bit of information - whether my key was valid or not. Can I trust the OTR session if he successfully verified my key and sent me this confirmation or is there still a risk of a man-in-the-middle attack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up asking on the [OTR's developer mailing](https://lists.cypherpunks.ca/pipermail/otr-dev/2015-April/002334.html) list and here's the response I got:

> On Wed, Apr 08, 2015 at 02:51:14PM +0200, Jacek Wielemborek wrote:
>
> > Hello,
> >
> > Here's something that keeps bugging me for a moment. It's a hypothetical
> >     situation, so please refrain from question like "how did you send the FP
> >     to your friend?".
> >
> > 1. My friend receives my OTR fingerprint over a secure channel (e.g.
> >        meeting in person), but he doesn't give the fingerprint to me and
> >        destroys the channel,
> > 2. Me and my friend establish a perfectly secure channel that has two
> >        limitations: my friend can only send messages to me (not the other way)
> >        and only one bit of information can be transferred.
> > 3. We agree that over this channel, he will tell me during a future OTR
> >        session whether my fingerprint matched what he received from me during
> >        step 1,
> > 4. We go back home, establish an OTR session over the internet, which
> >        isn't secure yet. My friend verifies my fingerprint based on what we got
> >        during step 1 and tells me whether it matched over channel from step 2,
> >
> > If the fingerprint he sees on the screen matches the thing he got from
> >     step 1, can I assume that there can be no man in the middle? In other
> >     words, is it possible to perform a one-way OTR MITM where my friend
> >     actually sees my real fingerprint, but when he responds, I can't see
> >     his, but one from the MITM?
> >
> > Hopefully I explained this clearly. Cheers,
> >     Jacek Wielemborek
>
> Jacek,
>
> Way back in OTRv1, this *was* actually possible.  However, the MITM
>   wouldn't be able to *read, write, or modify* the messages; the issue
>   was that your buddy would see your key as being the partner in the
>   conversation, while you would see the MITM as being your partner in
>   the conversation.  (The messages would *actually* be going to your
>   true buddy, though.)
>
> We upgraded the key exchange protocol in 2005 to address this problem,
>   and I do not believe a MITM could pull this off with OTRv2 or OTRv3
>   (unless one of the endpoints were compromised, of course).
>
> [Even better is to exchange a shared secret in your step 1 instead,
>   and then use the SMP to mutually authenticate your long-term keys. 
>   But this requires a secure channel in the *secrecy* sense, whereas
>   your version only requires a secure channel in the *authenticity*
>   sense; the latter is sometimes easier to pull off in practice.]
>   --  Ian Goldberg Associate Professor and University Research Chair Cheriton School of Computer Science, University of Waterloo Visiting
>   Professor, ESAT/COSIC, KU Leuven